# Dependency injection error pops up whenever I try to install a certain Discord Package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, discord

I'm really new to programming, but I felt like trying out some bot-development for my discord server, like one that will occasionally say hello to people when they join, however when I tried to install one of the Discord packages I got this error

> Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection'. Source(s) used: 'discord.net', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your [package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources). Nuget will try to find `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` from available sources, but apparently 'discord.net' and 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages' don't have this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection'. Source(s) used:
>   'discord.net', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

This error message always occurs when you want to install the package whose dependency package is not found. For example, I created a custom package(`MyCustomPKG`) that depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

[image]

And now I'll get the same issue if **nuget** can't find the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in all available package sources.

[image]

> To resolve that issue:

Add `nuget.org`(https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) as [package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) and make sure the checkbox is enabled.

[image]

**In addition:** If you're not using VS IDE, instead you're using `Nuget.exe`+`Nuget.config` file, add this line(`<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />`) to `Nuget.config`.